# Why is WETH balance of an address is wrong on hardhat fork?

Tags: transactions, hardhat, web3.py, balances

I have forked mainnet with hardhart with below command:

```
npx hardhat node --fork http://127.0.0.1:8545 --port 8546
```

When I get the balance of 0xbd497b28d443a5345674fef37c50d8fd68e7bd94, it shows it correctly:

```
http_provider = 'http://localhost:8546'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(http_provider))
WETH = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2'
weth = web3.eth.contract(address=WETH, abi=token_abi)
balance = weth.functions.balanceOf(address).call()
print('weth balance:', balance)
```

The output is `weth balance: 147652200000000000000`.

But when I try to make a swap on Uniswap, it shows different value:

```
impersonate_account(address)

fee = 3000
deadline = int(time.time()) + 5
quoted_amount_in = 1_000 * 10 ** 18
token0 = '0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE'
amount_out = 1 * 10 ** 18
func_args = (WETH, token0, fee, address, deadline, amount_out, quoted_amount_in, 0)

swap = router.encodeABI(fn_name='exactOutputSingle', args=[func_args])
txn = router.functions.multicall([swap]).transact({'from': address, 'gas': 1_000_000,
                                                   'gasPrice': web3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
                                                   'value': quoted_amount_in})
```

I know that the `quoted_amount_in` is more than my current balance (I am actually using it for other purpose, that's why it is greater), but when this transaction fails, it fails with:

```
 {'message': "sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. 
The max upfront cost is: 1000100000000000000000 and the sender's account only has: 445977470161794787514"}
```

Clearly, this account doesn't have this balance, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also faced the similar problem, mate.

445977470161794787514 is not about the WETH value in the account.
It is about the ETH value in the account and on my side, it was also not work correctly.

So to solve this problem, I get the accounts which the hardhat provide us. And send 10 ETH from one of the account to the impersonate_account.

Please try with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really answer my question, I want to increase the balance of wallets with setStorageAt, after which balance is still shown as 445977470161794787514

Comment: @Tugay. I don't know what does setSTorageAt means.
And also, this problem is caused because of hardhat fork. As you know, the error message is "sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx." and the way to solve this is to send Eth to the address. The wallets which hardhat provide to us have 1000eth so please use it to charge the eth.